# get id value from array of objects on mouse click

Tags: arrays, dictionary, filter

I have an array of objects that will expand and show an array list of grades on mouse click.

My Question: Is there a way to get a single id value from an `onClick` event?

For example, in the below array, when I click the button, I want to get `id:1` and NOT `id: [1,2,3]` when I click on `Sarah`.

I have tried `valueOf()`, `filter()`, `find()`, they all require comparing a value I am looking for to one I need, ie `students.filter((r)=> r.id === '1')` I need to do `students.filter((r)=> r.id)` but I get the result of `id:[1,2,3]` instead.

Here is a link to my [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-pond-fvwi7x?file=/src/Components/StudentContext.js) (you will notice my attempts are commented out). In the api all of the grades expand at once and I need only one at a time. I understand it is because this is an array that iterates, however I don't know if it is possible to get the id by its self on the click event.

```html
{
"students":
 [
 {"firstName":"Sarah",
 "grades":["78","100","87"],
 "id":"1"},
 {"firstName":"Bob",
 "grades":["75","89","82"],
 "id":"2"},
 {"firstName":"Laura",
 "grades":["88","82","81"],
 "id":"3"}
 ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer was to find the current id by passing in the event as a prop to `expandDiv()` function. I still am not able to successfully match the id to the button to toggle state.

```
const expandDiv = (e) => {
    setActive(!isActive)
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id)
  }
```